# database identity column not working

Tags: database, vb.net

I am creating a database application in vb.net. I have set  an identity column(is identity = true) in visual studio. However when I run my application no identity column is recognized. Where am I going wrong?

My connections string is :

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING LOCAL DATABASE\SkeduleringLD1.0\SkeduleringLD1.0\Databasis\Skeddatabasis.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

I have set this is the app.config file. I then open the connection with :

```
Public konneksie As New 
    SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("konneksie").ConnectionString)
```

The connection does open. But the identity columns seems to be a problem.

Comment: Do you mean in the database, or in the ADO.NET Datatable? What database engine are you using? Can you post your code?

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using Microsoft SQL Server that is built into Visual studio.

Comment: SQL Server is not built into Visual Studio.  Identity is a type of column not a name or datatype; but that code isnt doing anything with any table or column.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: What does the query look like?

Answer (score 1):

`Identity` is a reserved word, so you need to call it with `[Identity]` in your query, or use a different name for that column.

See [Reserved Keywords List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) for more

Comment: It was id. I have changed it to idoesskattings, When I run my application is still says :  'oesskattings' does not contain an identity column. Here is the code for the table :                                                                           [IdOesskattings]               INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [lidno]            VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [lidnaam]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [plantjaar]        INT          NULL,
    [stadium]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdOesskattings] ASC)
);

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general purpose utility method I use...

Assuming you have this declared:

```
Friend Shared ConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("konneksie").ToString
```

You can pass SQL Query and an instantiated DataTable into this:

```
Friend Shared Sub LoadData(SQL As String, ByRef TableObject As DataTable, Optional Clear As Boolean = True)
    If Clear Then TableObject.Clear()

    Using SqlConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        With New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SQL, SqlConnection)
            .SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 60
            .MissingSchemaAction = Data.MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
            .FillSchema(TableObject, SchemaType.Source)
            .Fill(TableObject)
            .Dispose()
        End With
    End Using

    For Each col As DataColumn In TableObject.PrimaryKey
        With col
            If .AutoIncrement Then
                ' Always set Step BEFORE Seed
                .AutoIncrementStep = -1
                .AutoIncrementSeed = -1
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```